# How to disable email notifications when confirming a donation in CiviCRM admin view?

Tags: civicontribute, email, recurring-contributions

When a admin user sets a contributors record on `civicrm/contribute?reset=1` from pending to completed an email is sent out.

Is it possible to turn off this email function for this email only.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the receipt?

There is a checkbox "Send Receipt?" when you modify an individual contributione. If you uncheck it, it shouldn't send the email.

Answer (score 1):

As Xavier says you need to uncheck the Send Receipt? box.
If you want the box to be unchecked by default, you could create an extension or use an existing one, as explained [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension), and implement the hook_civicrm_buildForm to set the is_email_receipt value to false:

```
function myextension_civicrm_buildForm( $formName, &$form ) {
  if ("CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution" == $formName) {
    $defaults = array ("is_email_receipt" => false);
    $form->setDefaults($defaults);
  }
}
```

I've added the example extension on github [here](https://github.com/mecachisenros/nocontributionreceipt), feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DO NOT EMAIL` flag for the contact for whom you don't want to send the email just before updating the status of the contribution.

You can find this in-

1. Open `Edit Contact Summary page` for the contact `civicrm/contact/add?reset=1&action=update&cid=<contact_id>`
2. Expand `Communication Preferences` tab.
3. Enable `Do Not Email` checkbox in the `Privacy` section.

Save this contact. Do remember to turn this flag off after completing your status update.
 Thx!

Comment: I think the question clearly is asking how to stop just the email that goes out from updating the status of the contribution. Your suggestion does not specifically address that unless you are suggesting that the set it to 'do not mail' change the contribution status, and then set it back.

Comment: updated the answer. Thx!